# SQL query to find the next version number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on a remote server that stores version numbers for our client side software. I use SOAP to handle requests. The client software sends a version number and I need to use SQL to find the next version numbers.

Here's the SQL that I use. I'm having a bit of a bad brain day, and I know this isn't correct but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

The create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sqlUpdateVersions` (
  `primary_key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `majorVS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `minorVS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `revisionVS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `buildVS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `filePK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customDBJarPK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`),
  KEY `filePK` (`filePK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

This is the SQL query to find a version #. I dumped in this version 1.1.0.0

```
select b.majorVS, b.minorVS,b.revisionVS, b.buildVS
 from sqlUpdateVersions b  where
 b.majorVS>=1 AND b.minorVS >=1 AND b.revisionVS>=0 AND b.buildVS>=10 
 ORDER BY b.majorVS,b.minorVS,b.revisionVS, b.buildVS
```

Now clearly I can tell this SQL is problematic. But how would I structure one that would return the next values, say 1.2.0.0 or 1.1.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: Are the `timestamp`s ordered according to version number?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski they're supposed to be, but it's not a guarantee. In theory they should go in order, but there's not really a mechanism to prevent that, only just that we hope we keep them in order.

Comment: and I suppose the same is true then of `primary_key` - no guarantee that they're in ascending order?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's correct. It's just to have a solid key to ID each row. I've just done that as best practice (I'm not super solid in SQL). Currently it's true that they're in order, but same as the timestamp, there's no hard and fast rule to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach:

```
select suv.*
from sqlUpdateVersions suv
where suv.majorVS > 1 or
      (suv.MajorVs = 1 and suv.minorVS > 1) or
      (suv.MajorVS = 1 and suv.minorVS = 1 and suv.revisionVS > 0) or
      (suv.MajorVS = 1 and suv.minorVS = 1 and suv.revisionVS = 0 and suv.buildVS > 10)
order by suv.MajorVS, suv.MinorVS, suv.revisionVS, suv.buildVS
```

You can also convert the versions to a bigint and do the comparison directly:

```
select suv.*
from (select suv.*,
             buildVS + (cast(1000 as bigint)*revisionVS +
                        (cast(1000 as bigint)*minorVS +
                         (cast(1000 as bigint)*majorVS
                         )
                        )
                       ) as bigVersion 
      from sqlUpdateVersions suv
     ) suv
 where bigversion > 1001000010
```

Comment: I like both approaches, the second one seems to make even more sense. Is there any performance differences?

Comment: The first version is probably a micro-iota faster, because it is doing no numeric calculations.  However, the difference in speed might not be noticeable at all.